# How do I use CANOpen on a Maxon's EPOS controller

Tags: c++, controller, canopen, epos

I am a french student in robotics and I have a project in which I have to connect 3 EPOS and my computer via EPOS 3.

I already wrote a programm in C++ to send bytes but I don't understand what to send and when.
For my project, I want to have the computer in master mode to send data to each controller (has orders) and when they all recieved it, I activate them by sending a global message and put them to sleep when they are finished

I read a lot of documentation and I think I want to initialze the NMT first ?
But I can't find anything such as an example or anything more than abstracts schematics.

I used a programm given by maxon to send bytes directly and the controller respond but never what I expect it to be.
And when I try to initialize it, the led on the controller shows me that it's not initialize.

Anyway thank you for everyone who will take the time to reply !

Comment: too much text,
you should stick to the important

Comment: You did not specify which Maxon software you are using, but it likely is 'EPOS studio', for which there is comprehensive beginner book available: https://www.maxongroup.com/medias/sys_master/root/8812125782046/Motion-Control-for-Newbies.pdf